# Understanding list view threshold (I expected an exception)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view-threshold

I created a list with numerous lookup columns (more than 12) and many many list items (more than 30.000).

- The "All List Items" view works perfectly. This is expected
- However I expected a sorting on a non-indexex text field column to throw a Throtteling Exception - regardless of the number of items returned.
- Also I expected a filtering on a non-indexed text field column to throw a Throtteling Exception - regardless of the number of items returned.
- Also I expected some issues because of the lookup threshold violation (> 12). But that's not my primary concern here.

Surprisingly the filtering and sorting works. Even if the returned results are more than 5000.
I disabled object model override (to rule out any "administrator specific" thresholds).

Can anyone explain to me why this is *not* throwing an exception?
I'm trying to understand how to design large lists applications.

**UPDATE:** My user is site collection admin - and also farm administrator.
Apparently turning off the "override rule" in CA (see screenshot) has no effect for site collection administrators or farm admins - the expected exception occurs with simple site "contributors".

[image: Central Administration Resource Throtteling Page for that WebApp]

Comment: can you share the web application throttling setting page's screen shot...under which account you login? is that account is part of Policy of web app?

Comment: There should be a separate setting for the threshold that applies to Farm admins